# Custom Event on JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, class, events

How can I create an event that is attached to a class object?

I have to create a class that has an event that should be called at a certain time. The class looks like this and should call the event `newMember` when a new one is added. What works is that I attach a custom event to the window and call it which is not my goal.

Not NodeJS.

```js
class Room {
    constructor() {
        this.members = {}
    }
    addMember(data) {
        if (!this.members[data.remotesid]) {
            this.members[data.socket] = data.identity
            //this.dispatchEvent();
        } else {
            console.log('Member already in room')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when a member is added to a Room. Like this 


var myRoom = new Room()
myRoom.addeventlistener('newMember', (member) => {
   console.log(member);
})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After being advised that I need to extend my class with `EventTarget`. I have now worked out this working solution.

```js
class Room extends EventTarget {
    #event;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.members = {}
    }
    addMember(data) {
        if (!this.members[data.remotesid]) {
            this.members[data.socket] = data
            this.#event = new CustomEvent("newMember", { detail: data });
            this.dispatchEvent(this.#event);
        } else {
            console.log('Member already in room')
        }
    }
}


var room = new Room();

room.addEventListener("newMember", function (e) {
    console.log("newMember event ", e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue and wouldn't have figured it out without this!